# Can I use the inverse map to show that the map is bijective (an isomorphism)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that a map $f: V \to V$ is an isomorphism.
I found the inverse map of it and wanna know if it will do that I write the inverse function down and show that it's a homomorphism.
Or do I have to show that it is injective and surjective?

I.e., $f(x) = x^2$ and I know that $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Thanks in advance
yours
pp

Comment: From the categorical point of view,  an  isomorphism is not a bijective homomorphism, but a homomorphism with an inverse homomorphism. Anyway, the existence of an inverse homomorphism implies bijectivity.

Comment: **Hint:** There is an equivalent definition of isomorphic involving the inverse function and the compostion.

Comment: @Allessio: do you mean that f ○ f(inv) = id ?

Comment: yes I do mean that.